# Custom json unmarshaler return empty fields

Tags: go

I've implemented a custom JSON unmarshaler, but for some reason it won't return the proper value -all fields come back nil.

For example:

```
type test struct {
  t string
}


func New(data string) (*test, error) {
    return &test{t: data}, nil
}

func (t *test) UnmarshalJSON(b []byte) error {
        tt, err := New(string(b))
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    t = tt
    return nil
}

func main() {
  str := `"hello"`

  b := []byte(str)
  t := &test{}
  err := json.Unmarshal(b, t)
  if err != nil {
    fmt.Printf("unmarshal error occurred: %#v", err)
  }
  fmt.Printf("%#v", t)
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/LuXkZQZHWz

The above code shows the output: `&main.test{t:""}`
Why doesn't it unmarshal the fields? i.e `&main.test{t:"hello"}`

Only when I dereference the pointers above, do I get the desired result.

i.e -

```
func (t *test) UnmarshalJSON(b []byte) error {
        tt, err := New(string(b))
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    *t = *tt
    return nil
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're assigning the local variable `t`, a pointer to `test`, to the value of the local variable `tt`, also a pointer to `test`. This has no effect on the value the original pointer `t` pointed to. You have to dereference the pointers to change the value it points to, rather than changing the local pointer itself:

```
*t = *tt
```

Comment: can you elaborate a bit more? So assigning a pointer to a pointer effectively does nothing? I would have expected the`t = tt` assignment to assign the address of `tt` to `t`

Comment: The variable `t` is a pointer variable within that method.  If you change the value of that pointer, you're changing what it points at, _not_ what's stored at what it originally pointed at.  Changing what it points out does not alter the original structure.  Method receivers in Go are _not_ the same as `this`/`self` pointers in languages like C++, they are value variables like any other.  The only way changes to them propagate out of the function is if you change the value of what they point at.

Comment: This may clarify: https://play.golang.org/p/tBCM0PfpEO.  Note that the address that `t` holds is changed within the method, and points at a struct that has been properly unmarshalled, but that change does not propagate out because you changed the value of `t` itself rather than what it pointed at.